# How to implement maintenance mode in custom php cms?

Tags: php

Ello,

I would like to make maintenance mode for my website, because i daily update files from development to production and website in that time website slows down or errors occurring for user at that time.

What the procedure for this kind of work. I would also like to allow users with right permissions to still login in website and use it normally (for testing purposes of implemented new features).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer really depends on the architecture of your cms. If there were no users needing a login during maintenance, you could use .htaccess to redirect browsers to a static page showing that maintenance is in progress. But if you need to be able to show some of the updated content, you have to make decision whether or not you want to show it to a specific visitor at cms level.

Comment: Hmm so i would create maintenance class and determine there if maintenance is enabled and if user that logins has right access let them trought to website else  display maintenance view.

Comment: Whichever way fits your current architecture, I really can't tell. One other alternative is to enable HTTP authentication for the site when in maintenance mode, but that could scare-off the visitors.